# Apply Group by and then select all

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a list which has following items :

**Id

Name

Currency

Fund**

I am applying **group by** on this list as follows :

```
var testData = from fl in fundsList
                           group fl by new { fl.Name } into groupedData
                           select new
                           {
                               groupedData.Key.Name,
                           };
```

But this gives me only **Name** in the selected data. What I want is apply group by on basis of **Name** and get all items i.e. **Id, Name, Currency and Fund** in *select*. I tried accessing others in select, but they don't come with Key.

Comment: But what about the other fields that are not grouped? Which value do you want to select from `Id`, `Currency` and `Fund` fields for each grouped `Name`? The `MAX`  the `Min` The `FirstOrDefault`??

Comment: Seem the expected result is not clear, I guess just only `GroupBy` is what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupedData` within your query implements `IEnumerable<YourEntity>` with items that belongs to that group, so you can easily do following:

```
var testData = from fl in fundsList
                           group fl by fl.Name into groupedData
                           select new
                           {
                              Name = groupedData.Key.Name,
                              Items = grp.ToList()
                           };
```

Or in method based query:

```
var testData = fundsList.GroupBy(fl => fl.Name)
                        .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Items = g.ToList() });
```

Every item withint `testData` collection will have two properties:

- `Name` with group name
- `Items` with all items that belongs to the group

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var testData = fundsList.GroupBy(fl => fl.Name);
```

Now you will get an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<T>>`, which containes many key => valueCollection items.

Answer (score 1):

```
var testData = from fl in fundsList
                           group fl by new { fl.Name } into groupedData
                           select new
                           {
                              GroupName=  groupedData.Key.Name,
                              Items = grp.ToList()
                           };
```